# which method iOS will call when enter by notification?

Tags: ios, ios7

when my app in background and iOS get a notification, after use type the notification enter my app, which method iOS will call? Because I need to open some view controller after user tap the notification to enter my app.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

the above method can not distinguish my app is opened from background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an app receives a notification while in the **foreground**, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` will get called.

However, when app is in **background** and it's launched by tapping on the notification, `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called with launch option having a key named `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`. The value of this key will be an `NSDictionary` with payload of your remote notification.

Hope this answers your question.

PS. A nice article on [UIApplicationDelegate Launch Options](http://nshipster.com/launch-options/)